# Inverse function of $f(x)=e^{x/2}$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse

How would you find the inverse function of $f(x)=e^{x/2}$?

Comment: This is the same as setting $y = e^{x/2}$, and then solving for $x$ in terms of $y$. Are you familiar with how that is done? (Hint: logarithms)

Comment: *Real-valued..* $f(x) = e^{g(x)} \iff \log f(x) = g(x).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y = \exp(x/2) \implies \log_e(y) = \log_e(\exp(x/2)) = x/2 \implies x = 2 \log_e(y)$$

Comment: this is wrong abswer

Comment: @AdiDani: No, it's not. $\log_e$ is the same thing as $\ln$.

Comment: @Hans Lundmarkt. It is wrong in sense that $x=2\log_e(y)$ is not inverse but needs to interchange x and y to  $y=2\log_e(x)$

Comment: @AdiDani: The answer gives $x=f^{-1}(y)$ instead of $y=f^{-1}(x)$. So what? It's the same function $f^{-1}$ no matter what variables you use for writing it.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=y=e^{\frac{x}{2}}$$
inverse is $x=e^{\frac{y}{2}}\iff\ln x=\ln e^{\frac{y}{2}}\iff \ln x =\frac{y}{2}\iff y=2\ln x$